# Change @observable property don't rerender observer component in my project with mobx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I have a problem with Mobx in my project. Changing property in my store by action don't fire rerendering component. I annotated the `@action`, the field with `@observer` and component with HoC `observer`.

I did a minimal setup to represent the problem on StackBlizt : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-dwqnm5?file=TestComponent.tsx

After click button Token should change.

[image]

Index.tsx

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <StoreProvider store={new UserStore()}>
      <div>
        <h1>Hello REACT!</h1>
        <TestComponent />
      </div>
    </StoreProvider>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

StoreContext.tsx

```js
export const StoreContext = createContext<UserStore>({} as UserStore);

export type StoreComponent = FC<{
  store: UserStore;
  children: ReactNode;
}>;

export const StoreProvider: StoreComponent = ({
  children,
  store
}): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={store}>{children}</StoreContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

UserStore.ts

```js
export default class UserStore {
  @observable
  public authToken: string = "null";

  @action
  changeAuth = (auth: string) => {
    this.authToken = auth;
  };
}
```

TestComponent.tsx

```js
function TestComponent() {
  const { changeAuth, authToken } = useContext(StoreContext);

  const handleClick = () => {
    changeAuth("TEST AUTH");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click to change Token in store</button>
      <br />
      Token: {authToken}
      <br />
    </div>
  );
}

export default observer(TestComponent);
```

**What I did not notice?**

Comment: Are you using MobX version 6?

Comment: @Danila yes
    "mobx": "^6.0.1",
    "mobx-react": "^7.0.0",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were using MobX 6 then you now need to use `makeObservable` method inside constructor to achieve same functionality with decorators as with MobX 5 before:

```
import { makeObservable } from "mobx"

export default class UserStore {
  @observable
  public authToken: string = "null";

  @action
  changeAuth = (auth: string) => {
    this.authToken = auth;
  };

  constructor() {
    // Just call it here
    makeObservable(this);
  }
}
```

Although there is new thing that will probably allow you to drop decorators altogether, `makeAutoObservable`:

```
import { makeAutoObservable } from "mobx"

export default class UserStore {
  // Don't need decorators now
  public authToken: string = "null";

  // Don't need decorators now
  changeAuth = (auth: string) => {
    this.authToken = auth;
  };

  constructor() {
    // Just call it here
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }
}
```

More info here
https://mobx.js.org/migrating-from-4-or-5.html
and
https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html